# Marker on user location in Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I mark current user location by a custom marker. I draw it once and in `OnLocationChange` listener I change it position according to user location, but sometimes there is a duplicate markers on the map. Why? Do you have any ideas? And is it good idea to change marker position in `OnLocationChange` listener?

I drawing marker:

```
currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(currentUserLocation.latitude, currentUserLocation.longitude))
                    .title("Current Location"));
```

and changing his position:

```
currentUserLocationMarker.setPosition(locLatLng);
```

My method looks like below. I invoke it once in `onCreateView()` and in `OnMyLocationChangeListener()`.

```
if (currentUserLocationMarker == null) {
            currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(currentUserLocation.latitude, currentUserLocation.longitude))
                    .title("Current Location"));
        } else {
            currentUserLocationMarker.setPosition(locLatLng);
        }
```

I suppose that better solution is draw once, and changing it position instead drawing, clearing and drawing again all the time.

Removing marker by calling method `.remove()` is acceptable, but clearing whole map, in the case of I have many markers and e.g. polylines drawn on the map is bad idea.

It would be useful if the map had a separate methods for remove markers and polylines, but now there is a one method `.clear()` which clear everything.

Comment: While you are changing the location then remove the previous one Marker..

Comment: Yes, I tried, but somehow I lost the reference for drawn marker.

Comment: When you change your location then try to remove previous and make a new Marker with new Locations...

Comment: `sometimes there is a duplicate markers on the map` is not a good description of the issue. In particular please make a note on where is the `addMarker` function executed.

Comment: I wrote above that I tried, I saved marker reference to field and for every change location I was removing the previous marker and draw again new one, but was happened that I had two markers on the map until I cleared the entire map using the `.clear()` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description I can only say that it can only happen if currentUserLocationMarker becomes null between function call. try debugging and using logcat.